# unable to update database table value from php function

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a value in the database but for some reason its not updating, I have a page from where the admin can suspend a user, the suspend function is called from that page, can someone please tell me whats wrong with my code.

```
 function suspend($table,$ID)
 {

  $db = new Connection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);
  $ID = mysql_real_escape_string($ID);

   $db->query('UPDATE users SET suspended= "1" WHERE ID = "'.$ID.'"');
   setMessage('Suspended successfully.', 1);
 }
```

The function runs because the message is displayed

The table scheme is as follows:

> Field ---- ---Type--------Null--- ---- Default
>
> ID------------int(10)------No----------Auto Increment
>
> suspended---tinyint(1)--Yes----------0

Comment: I assume your `ID` is integer, so update your query: `WHERE ID = "$ID"`

Comment: try $db->query("UPDATE users SET suspended= '1' WHERE ID = '$ID'");

Comment: Didn't help @bartek :(

Comment: If `suspended` is also `integer`, try with `"UPDATE users SET suspended = 1 WHERE ID = $ID;"`

Comment: @bartek This is not an issue, in mysql, integers can be quoted too.

Comment: @cypher `MySQL` seems to be really crazy then. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @bartek [you don't know the half of it](http://i57.tinypic.com/2kjz9w.png) :)

Comment: yes suspended and ID both are integers,

Comment: @cypher That's why [I love my PostgreSQL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emgJtr9tIME) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query..

```
    function suspend($table,$ID)
    {

    $db = new Connection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);
     $ID = mysql_real_escape_string($ID);

     $sql= "UPDATE users SET suspended='1' WHERE ID='".$ID."'";
     $db->query($sql);

     setMessage("Suspended successfully", 1);
     }
```

i edited the code.

Comment: This brings up the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Are you sure u have the column name ID in capital letters . if not try with this one..  `$db->query("UPDATE users SET suspended='1' WHERE id='"$ID"'");`

Comment: @user3234352 Won't make any difference. MySQL is case insensitive.

Comment: Yes the column name is ID and as @cypher said it's case insensitive anyways :(

Comment: @user3234352 this doesnt show the error but still the value is not updated even though the message is getting displayed :( Any ideas ?

Comment: @user3297381 update your question and post your `table schema`